# CSS inheritance in Django templates

Tags: css, django, django-templates

I want to split my CSS into multiple files to match with each template and app. But the following problem keeps me baffled.
In the `base.css` of my `base.html` template, I have an element class `button` declared as following:

```
.button {
  ...
}
```

So, all buttons should follow this css.
In an app called `table`, in a template `table_view.html` that extends `base.html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<link href="{% static 'css/table.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" />
...
     <button class="btn-avail table">Table</button>
...
{% endblock %}
```

I have a different format for class `btn-avail` in `table.css`. But I could not get it to load and override the base format. If I change the class name to `button` (of `base.css`), it reflects the base format. Or if I place `btn-avail` in the `base.css`, then its format is correctly reflected.

In my `settings.py`, here is my static directory:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.
Update: here is the folder structure for app `table`
`table/static/css/table.css`.
And the `base.css` sits here: `project_root/static/css`.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS snippet you've posted applies to any element with a *class* of 'button' - the `button` element you've defined in the template does not have that class.

Comment: I guess my question is why doesn't it load the ```table.css```. I think I may miss something in settings?

Comment: That stylesheet is not getting loaded at all? Can you share a snippet of the rendered HTML?

Comment: OK, I found out why: something about "caching". I have to refresh the page with ```Ctrl+F5```. I think my settings and folder structure is correct. Thanks. Closing this.